# AWS Amplify:: Calling GraphQL API from Lambda Function produces "Not Authorized to access updateCustomUser" on type Mutation

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

I am following this documentation: https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/graphql-from-lambda/q/platform/js/#iam-authorization

to create a a lambda function that calls a GraphQL API, however, I recieve "Not Authorized to access updateCustomUser on type Mutation.

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
type CustomUser @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private, provider: iam}]) {
  id: ID!
  userId: String
  enrolledFor: CourseType
}
```

and Lambda Function that looks something like this:

```
import crypto from '@aws-crypto/sha256-js';
import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node';
import { SignatureV4 } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4';
import { HttpRequest } from '@aws-sdk/protocol-http';
import { default as fetch, Request } from 'node-fetch';

const { Sha256 } = crypto;
const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_<YOUR_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
const AWS_REGION = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-1';

const mutation = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdateCustomUser($input: UpdateCustomUserInput!) {
    updateCustomUser(input: $input) {
      id
      enrolledFor
    }
  }
`;

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const endpoint = new URL(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT);

  const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: 'appsync',
    sha256: Sha256
  });

  const variables = {
    input: {
      id: event.userId,
      isEnrolledFor: "CS"
    },
  };

  const requestToBeSigned = new HttpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      host: endpoint.host,
    },
    hostname: endpoint.host,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: mutation, variables }),
    path: endpoint.pathname,
  });

  const signed = await signer.sign(requestToBeSigned);
  const request = new Request(endpoint, signed);

  let statusCode = 200;
  let body;
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    body = await response.json();
    if (body.errors) statusCode = 400;
  } catch (error) {
    statusCode = 500;
    body = {
      errors: [
        {
          message: error.message
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
};
```

Although the documentation mentions The CLI will automatically configure the Lambda execution IAM role to call the GraphQL API. I am receiving unauthorized Execption. Can anyone provide me any insights on what's going on here.

I appreciate ya reading this. Thanks for your time

Reading Documentation

Comment: I used API as an authorizer instead of the Signature and crap!

Comment: yes but what does your model look like. It must be public

Comment: Sorry yes you may be right, as seemingly the SDK from node.js v18+ is no longer required. I might try that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double-check that the Lambda function has the required IAM permission?

It might also be the signature that is wrongly generated. I'd recommend this package [aws-appsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-appsync) which handles the signature process for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about version but I had to upgrade to 13.5+
Also, had to **update the schema** and run > **amplify push --force api**
It asked me if I wanted to update the mutations, say yes.
Voilà it works.

The documentation I followed to the letter seeing up the function last was the issue, hence why some am update the schema, so I expect to run into this problem on my next lambda. At which point aging a space to the schema seemingly works too.

I have escalated the issue, and the documentation issues to AWS, so hopefully it gets sorted, I was told there is a bug returning a 4XX error that end users cannot see.

Follow this documentation:
https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/graphql-from-lambda/q/platform/js/#iam-authorization
**UDATE YOUR SCHEMA!
Run> amplify push --force api.**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered pretty much the same issue.

Resolution: I found a solution in the Amplify documentation. It's a bit counterintuitive, but even though I deployed my Lambda function with Amplify, the fix was under the section for "Function deployed with other tools".

**Steps**:

1. Refer to this section of the Amplify Docs: [Customize Authorization Rules - Grant Lambda Function Access to GraphQL API](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/customize-authorization-rules/#grant-lambda-function-access-to-graphql-api).
2. Navigate to the tab titled "Function deployed with other tools".
3. You need to add your Lambda execution role to adminRoleNames in your GraphQL API configuration. In my case, this role is infra-admin, which manages all Amplify deployments.

By following these steps, I was able to resolve the issue.